# Windows 8.1 Internet Connection Sharing: Mobile Device says "No Internet Access"

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1, windows-phone, ics, mobile-broadband

I have a laptop running Windows 8.1 (without Update 1). I have setup ICS like this:

1. Charms > Settings > Network > Network Name (Mobile Broadband)
2. Share this Connection = on

It turns on successfully, and my mobile (Lumia 520 with Cyan update) picks it up and connects, but then says that there is no internet access.

Interestingly enough, it was connected about 15 hours ago - but half way through my mobile updating apps, it just stopped. After checking WiFi settings, it gave the above message. Now it simply will not connect.

I have tried renaming the network; using a different USB port for my 4G stick; and restarting the associated service (ICS).

Anything else I could do to resolve this?

(P.S: I don't want to use the command line method to share the connection. The built-in method worked before, and so it should be fixable. Besides, I'm sure that the built-in method uses a similar methodology to what you would do in a previous OS.)

Comment: "half way through my mobile updating apps, it just stopped" -- maybe the problem is with the mobile?

Comment: I don't actually know... Unfortunately, I don't have another phone to test with, nor do I have another PC that I can share with... Is there anything I could reset on my Lumia?

Comment: You could try asking on http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

try going to settings/network/ *tap on your mobile network* (in my case it was O2)/ *then under access point you see NAME from the dropbox chose*: MY OWN SETTINGS (or anything called similar)
*and into the slot for APN write the APN Name given by the internet provider* (in my case with O2 it was simply INTERNET so I would use the same as sort of general APN name) *leave other boxes empty click apply and see if your connection restores*

Comment: It was set to that by default.